# Split the string 3 times and inserted into database - Java

Tags: java

Its scraping tool, while running getting more length of string value like `152263`.
I want to insert this string value into the  db (SQL - nvarchar(max))
the entire length not fit in a single column (`after 42600 its truncated`), so i alter the table adding one more columns and insert the value.

```
 if (fullText.length() > 42600) {
     preparedStatement.setString(35, fullText.substring(0, 42500));
     preparedStatement.setString(36, fullText.substring(42500, fullText.length()));
 } else {
     preparedStatement.setString(35, fullText);
     preparedStatement.setString(36, "");
 }
```

the above one working perfectly for 2 columns.
some cases its exit more than two column
let me know how can i split into 3 times (equal to string length) and stored into 3 columns in sql db.

Comment: Did you try using a loop that's operating on the "rest" string, i.e. the right part when splitting at position 42500? You'd repeat your process with the right part until it doesn't have to be split anymore. However note that this would require you to either dynamically add columns (not trivial) or use multiple rows (which might not be trivial as well seeing that your statement already has 34 other params). Thus I'd recommend thinking about a redesign or use another column type (e.g. Postgres has a `text` type, other dbs probably have something similar).

Comment: Doesn't your DB support Blob objects? The best is to use a Blob rather than splitting it into multiple columns. If you need to use multiple columns - rather than the solution - use a one-many relationship and use a separate data table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (fullText.length() > 42600) {
        preparedStatement.setString(35, fullText.substring(0, 42500));
        if (fullText.length() > 85000) {
            preparedStatement.setString(36, fullText.substring(42500, 85000));
            preparedStatement.setString(37, fullText.substring(85000, fullText.length()));
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setString(36, fullText.substring(42500, fullText.length()));
        }
    } else {
        preparedStatement.setString(35, fullText);
        preparedStatement.setString(36, "");
        preparedStatement.setString(37, "");
    }
```

Comment: Try that with a string of let's say length 50000. What would `fullText.substring(85000, fullText.length())` do?

Answer (score 0):

Check length against a given limit and compare from longest to shortest range. Not sure if you want to store "" or NULL in empty columns

```
String first = "";
String middle = "";
String last = "";

if (fullText.length > SPLIT_LIMIT * 2) {
    last = fullText.substring(SPLIT_LIMIT * 2 + 1);
}

if (fullText.length > SPLIT_LIMIT) {
    middle = fullText.substring(SPLIT_LIMIT + 1, SPLIT_LIMIT * 2);
    first = fullText.substring(0, SPLIT_LIMIT * 2);
} else {
    first = fullText;
}

preparedStatement.setString(35, first);
preparedStatement.setString(36, middle);
preparedStatement.setString(37, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using a loop to make a flexible count of colums:

```
    String text = "";
    int idCounter = 35;
    while(text.length() > 42600){
        preparedStatement.setString(idCounter, text.substring(0, 42600));
        text = text.substring(42601,text.length());
        idCounter++;
    }
    preparedStatement.setString(idCounter, text);
```

(not tested)